# Do I Have To Use Eclipse (Or Similar IDE)

Tags: java, eclipse, jgrasp

Is it necessary to use Eclipse (or similar high-level IDE counterpart) for a professional programmer?

I kept running into errors with Eclipse when setting up projects and I got hooked on JGrasp for its simplicity;  struggling with Eclipse was ultimately detracting from coding time.   I understand that Eclipse offers many features beyond that of a lightweight environment like JGrasp which could save effort (lending to more effeficent use of time), and also allows for much better organization with more complex projects.  I have not yet tried Netbeans.

But I guess I am simply asking if you walked in on your colleague and he was using JGrasp, would you look at him funny? ...or take him less seriously.

Comment: A previous post should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927308/choosing-java-tools-ide-and-compiler-for-beginners

Comment: The answer is: no, you don't _have_ to. You can use any environment that converts java to class files, even `javac` with nothing else. As to whether or not people will look at you funny, that's where this question crosses over into subjectivity.

Comment: Your about to get a huge discussion rather than an answer on this one.  That said, in my experience, I simply use what the other devs are using to keep things consistent.  If you all use the same tool(s) you can help each other when you have tool issues.

Comment: Thank you AurA, took a look.  The emphasis is on "in a professional environment".  Obviously in some situations, you will simply want to use what everyone else is using for convenience.  But in general...

Comment: I'm guessing the downvoter uses Netbeans?

Comment: Alright, I learned my lesson.  I have now saved more time _using_ Eclipse than _learning_ to use it... Now can someone please up-vote me back to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any IDE of your choice. Paid/free/opensource/’developed by you’/text-editor whatever suits you.

As far as professional development is concerned its mostly not a developers choice but what is already selected in project plan.
Only if you have some say in that decision making, will get  you tools of your choice.

“… would you look at him funny ?..or take him less seriously.?” Now this depends on one’s personal attitude, usually No.
Sometimes I wonder why kids in schools use eclipse/netbeans (heavily loaded for EE dev which only makes them sluggish compared to standered version of same IDE) over notepad/BlueJ etc for simple programs. (Not discouraging it, logic is right tool in the project context)

If you are developing applications with  third party frameworks then the IDE integration helps a lot.
Example : struts, hibernate, svn integration, also running a web application from within eclipse/netbeans saves a lot of dev effort.

Suggestion: Don’t try to avoid the learning curve.

bstar55’s point is good too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I would. Use eclipse. It's what most professionals use and it really will help you code faster. Eclipse is especially helpful when it comes to exploring methods when using classes that you aren't familiar with because it gives you a little menu with the methods available to that object. JGrasp is good if you are still learning the fundamentals of programming in general. Search youtube for eclipse tutorials and try to use eclipse from now on... even on simple projects so you can get the basics down for when you jump to more complex ones.

Edit: Netbeans is good too, but pretty much every java dev I work with (I'm a java dev too) uses eclipse. Netbeans and eclipse have a lot of the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Though setting up eclipse and creating a project is relatively easier, to answer your question straight forward, No you don't have to use Eclipse to be a professional programer. There are lots of other IDE's available

- IntelliJ
- NetBeans
- BlueJ

but choosing between them is a matter of own choice (I use Eclipse myself and have used all the above some point of time in my professional life). If your into serious programming with Maven, Android, JSF etc then I recommend you to use some advanced IDE's

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse and netbeans are equally good. Eclipse has so many inbuilt packages

But if you are giving priority to speed of execution and flexibility, you may use editors like sublime