# Cannot invoke method getSize() on the array type (Class) MitarbeiterListe[]

Tags: java

So I have two Java classes. There is the class `Mitarbeiter` and class `MitarbeiterListe`.
`Mitarbeiter` generates the object `Mitarbeiter` with `id` and `name`. The `Mitarbeiter` should be saved in an array which is initialized in the constructor of the class `MitarbeiterListe`.

I wrote a method `getSize()` which should return the number of `Mitarbeiter` saved in the array.

Unfortunately I can't use `getSize()` in my `main()`. It gives me the error:

```
Cannot invoke getSize() on the array type MitarbeiterListe[]
```

Code:

```
/*********************MITARBEITERListe********************/
public class MitarbeiterListe {

    static Mitarbeiter[] liste;

    public MitarbeiterListe(int index) {

         liste = new Mitarbeiter[index];

    }

    public static int getSize() {
        int size =0;
        for(int i=0; i< liste.length; i++) {
            if(liste[i]!= null) {
                size++;
            }
        }
        return size;
    }
}

/**********************MITARBEITER************************/

public class Mitarbeiter extends Main {

    private int id;
    private static int idMax =1;
    private String name;



    public Mitarbeiter(String name) {
        id = idMax++;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

/**********************MAIN************************/

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Mitarbeiter m1 = new Mitarbeiter("Tim");
        Mitarbeiter m2 = new Mitarbeiter("Anton");

        MitarbeiterListe l1[] = new MitarbeiterListe[5];


        //Here I'll get the Error
        System.out.println(l1.getSize());
}
```

Comment: Why are the `liste` field and `getSize()` method `static`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting error at `System.out.println(l1.getSize());`

Because your `l1` is an array instance as you did this : `MitarbeiterListe l1[] = new MitarbeiterListe[5];`
And as a result `l1[].getSize()` is a *compilation error* as for array there is no function like `getSize()` available.

As for `l1` you can invoke only functions of `array` , see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9297956/2065799).

And in @Indestruktible answer you can see how to invoke your defined `getSize()`.

Moreover, based on your code suggest you to go through below please :

- [Java: when to use static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods)
- [Implements vs extends: When to use? What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839131/implements-vs-extends-when-to-use-whats-the-difference) (Since you extended `Main` class)
- [How to instantiate an object in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986220/how-to-instantiate-an-object-in-java)
- [How to initialize an array of objects in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889034/how-to-initialize-an-array-of-objects-in-java)
- [Choosing Java tools (IDE and compiler) for beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927308/choosing-java-tools-ide-and-compiler-for-beginners)

(Remember > ***donot use IDE to learn code, rather use it to code***)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes its solved, thanks a lot for your help and your recommendations

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `5` to the *constructor* of `MitarbeiterListe`, not create a new array of `MitarbeiterListe`-objects:

```
MitarbeiterListe l1 = new MitarbeiterListe(5);
System.out.println(l1.getSize());
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, `liste` and `getSize` should be an instance members, not `static` variables / methods, otherwise the constructor doesn't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*********************MITARBEITERListe********************/

public class MitarbeiterListe {

    private Mitarbeiter[] liste;

    public MitarbeiterListe(int index) {
        liste = new Mitarbeiter[index];
    }

    public int getSize() {
        int size =0;
        for(int i=0; i< liste.length; i++) {
            if(liste[i]!= null) {
                size++;
            }
        }
        return size;
    }
}

/*********************MITARBEITER********************/

public class Mitarbeiter extends MitarbeiterListe {

    private int id;
    private int idMax = 1;
    private String name;

    public Mitarbeiter(String name, int index) {
        super (index);
        id = idMax++;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

/************************MAIN***********************/

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Mitarbeiter m1 = new Mitarbeiter("Tim", 2);
        Mitarbeiter m2 = new Mitarbeiter("Anton", 3);

        System.out.println(m1.getSize());
        System.out.println(m2.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to explain how it answers the question.